# Python sentiment classification

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

Hi i am trying to classify certain text file by using sentiment classifier package.The following program works fine for a single sentence i.e.,

```
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
sentences = ['i love u']
pos_score, neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores(sentences)
print pos_score, neg_score
```

But when done the following way by using an xls file to classify every record the result is a 0.0 for both positive and negative score.
Please help me out.

```
import openpyxl
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sentiment2.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.columns[0]
for cellObj in sheet.columns[0]:
    sentences = cellObj.value
    print(sentences)
    pos_score, neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores(sentences)
    print pos_score, neg_score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`senti_classifier.polarity_scores()` function](https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier/blob/master/src/senti_classifier/senti_classifier.py#L207) expects a *list of strings* as an argument, but you are passing a single string. Put it into the list:

```
pos_score, neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores([sentences])
```